# NURBS surface in 2D

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a NURBS surface in 2D from X, Y coordinates of a matrix with MxN M rows and N columns, and to be able to adjust it from LxK Ctrl points.

I am using a Bezier algorithm to generate only one horizontal curve each time that I move a Ctrl point. But the idea is to move one Ctrl point and recalculate the entire mesh based on that movement.

Also, to be able to generate the MxN points based on distribution of the Ctrl points. These points are not the same as the Ctrl points.

How can I generate the MxN points after a movement of one Ctrl point in order to build a new Mesh?

The weight of each Ctrl points are the same in this case.

Current app so far:

[image]

Comment: @user3884804 Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand what you question is. It sounds like you are off to a good start, what is your question?

Comment: I am sorry. I already edited the original post. Thank you.